# Limesurvey - Results distribution

Tags: authentication, survey, limesurvey

Is there a way to make the survey results available without the need of user authentication?

For example. The link below allow for the user to see survey results, but he/she needs to be login as admin.

https://limesurvey-home/index.php/admin/statistics/sa/simpleStatistics/surveyid/924492

Answer (score -1):

There is a setting for allowing statistics to be public.

Take a look here: https://manual.limesurvey.org/Statistics#Public_Statistics

> LimeSurvey includes functionality to display simple statistics to the general public or to your participants after they have completed filling out an online survey.
>
> There are two steps involved in activating and displaying statistics to your participants. Firstly you must enable public statistics for your survey (by default this is turned off). This setting is in your main survey toolbar, General Settings – in the Presentation and Navigation Tab. Look for the setting "Public Statistics". There is also a setting here called "Show graphs in public statistics" which – if turned on – will show graphs as well as the counts (by default only numerical statistics are displayed).
>
> Once you’ve set your survey to display statistics, you need to indicate question-by-question which statistics are displayed to your participants. By default, no questions are selected for display.
>
> You choose which questions will be shown in the public statistics page by editing each question. In the Statistics Tab for each question is an option "Show in public statistics". Once you set this setting to "On" the question will be included on the public statistics page.

Thanks!